# Using Azure Data Factory output in Logic App

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

- I have a logic app that runs on occurrence initially that runs an ADF
  pipeline which outputs a folder of files.
- Then, I use a **List Blobs** action to pull one specific file
  from the newly made folder and place its path on a queue.
- And once a message is placed on that queue, it triggers the run of
  another ADF pipeline.

The issue is I have not seen a way to get the output of the first ADF pipeline to put on the queue. I have tried to cheat within the **List Blobs** action that is sequential to the 1st ADF pipeline by explicitly searching the name of the output folder because it will be the same every time.

However, even after the 1st ADF is ran and produces the folder, within the first instance of this Logic App being ran the **List Blobs** can't find the folder and says the file path is not found.

Only after I run the Logic App a **second** time the folder is finally found which is not at all optimal. How can I fix this ? I prefer to keep everything in one logic app. Are there other Azure tools that can help in addition?

Answer (score 0):

I am not having the details of the implementation but i am wondering if the message is written by the first pipeline is only used as a signal the second pipeline ? if thats the case why you cannot you call the second pipeline on completion of the first one ? may be these pipelines are on different ADF's ?

I suggest you to read and see if you can use the [Event triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger)